# Extracting Generic Struct Values by Reflection

Tags: go

I'm trying to extract all of the values for a struct into a string slice.

```
func structValues(item Item) []string {
    values := []string{}
    e := reflect.ValueOf(&item).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldValue := e.Field(i).Interface()
        values = append(values, fmt.Sprintf("%#v", fieldValue))
    }
    return values
}
```

I'd like to use this function with any struct, so I thought I could just change the type signature to `func structValues(item interface{})` but then I got a panic:

> panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on interface Value

Working example: https://repl.it/@fny/stackoverflow61719532

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to use this function with any struct ...

You *can* do this, but note that it gives up type-safety.  Moreover, the only way to do this is to allow a call with *any* type, not just any type that is some structure type, so you have to check that what you got was in fact some struct type:

```golang
func structValues(item interface{}) {
    if reflect.ValueOf(item).Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        ... do something here ...
    }
```

Having made that check—or deferring it slightly, or omitting it to allow `reflect` to panic instead—you then need to replace `reflect.ValueOf(&item).Elem()` with the simpler `reflect.ValueOf(item)`.

If you wish to allow pointers to structures as well as actual structures, you can make that happen pretty simply by using `reflect.Indirect` first.  The result is:

```golang
func structValues(item interface{}) []string {
    e := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(item))
    if e.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("not a struct")
    }
    values := []string{}
    for i := 0; i < e.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldValue := e.Field(i).Interface()
        values = append(values, fmt.Sprintf("%#v", fieldValue))
    }
    return values
}
```

Leave out the `reflect.Indirect` if you want to make sure that callers do their own indirection when they have a pointer.

(Note that the `panic` here is not very friendly.  If you want proper debugging, consider either just printing the struct directly with `%v` or `%#v`, or for something much more thorough, the [spew package](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew).)

[Complete example here on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BvggRL7miqx) uses your `type Item struct` from your own link.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer--especially the detail in this and other responses! Just getting started with Go, so every tidbit has been enlightening.

Comment: Is there any way to access tags from the `Value` that's returned by these Field calls? (e.g. e.Field(i).Tag)

Comment: The fields are attached to the *type*, not to the value. So you have to use `reflect.TypeOf` to get the type, and go from there to the fields and their tags. (The index numbers in the `reflect.Type` match those in the `reflect.Value`, so if `t` is the appropriate type, use `t.Field(i).Tag`.)